# Why can't the typeclass constraint be inferred and get ambiguous instead?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

For the following code,

```
func :: Show a => a -> a
func = id

func3 = func . func
```

the compile complains with messages

```
Ambiguous type variable `c0' in the constraint:
  (Show c0) arising from a use of `func'
Possible cause: the monomorphism restriction applied to the following:
  func3 :: c0 -> c0 (bound at test.hs:6:1)
Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature
              or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction.
```

However, querying its type in GHCi works just fine.

```
*Main> :t func . func
func . func :: Show c => c -> c
```

What's happening here? Is there any way to have the type of `func3` automatically inferred?

p.s. Following the instructions in the message do help, but I don't understand what's going on here.

Comment: Alas GHC's "probably fix" suggestions are sometimes quite misleading, but this one is spot on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three ways you can compile your code.

#### Method 1

You *can* disable the monomorphism restriction.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

The monomorphism restriction comes into play because `func3` is not defined using function syntax.  Which leads to method 2:

#### Method 2

If you had done this instead:

```
func3 x = func . func $ x
```

Everything would have been fine.  The monomorphism restriction is a rule that protects you from "accidentally" defining a polymorphic value.  It is known to be a little too restrictive in some common cases, and it is a deviation from standard Hindley-Milner type inference.

#### Method 3

Of course, the final thing you can do, is to give your function an explicit type signature.

```
func3 :: Show a => a -> a
func3 = func . func
```

The monomorphism restriction means that any value which is declared without function syntax (i.e., the left hand side of the `=` has no parameters) will not get a polymorphic type derived automatically.

Comment: I see. During type inference, `func3 = func . func` is inferred to have type `Show c => c -> c` for some fresh variable `c`. By the monomorphism restriction, `func3` is *not* being further generalized. The compiler then have to determine which instance `func3` is going to use, hence the message.

Comment: That syntactic restriction remind me of the value restriction of ML, though they have different purpose & motivation.